# How to restart kubernetes master?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to restart the actual Kubernetes master related processes / services.

So this would relate to kubelete / scheduler etc etc.

How can this be done?

Comment: Old post, but I was trying to do the same thing. This may help - https://gist.github.com/BrandonPotter/48707c0149390ace71009ccfcda7343d

Comment: Have solutions below helped ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

```
for SERVICES in etcd kube-apiserver kube-controller-manager kube-scheduler flanneld; do
    systemctl restart $SERVICES
    systemctl enable $SERVICES
    systemctl status $SERVICES
done
```

And

```
for SERVICES in kube-proxy kubelet flanneld docker; do
    systemctl restart $SERVICES
    systemctl enable $SERVICES
    systemctl status $SERVICES
done
```

Credit for this goes to [BrandonPotter/restart-kubectl-master-services](https://gist.github.com/BrandonPotter/48707c0149390ace71009ccfcda7343d)

Comment: Just curious, where are you seeing these systemctl services?? I see things like kube-apiserver when I do "kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system", but "systemctl status kube-apiserver" gives "Unit kube-apiserver.service could not be found.". The only K8s-related services I have are kubelet and docker. Using CentOS 7.5 w/ K8s 1.13.0 (although this was also the case when using 1.10.0).

Answer (score 0):

I do this way:

```
docker container ls | grep k8s
```

Then:

```
docker restart container_id
```

Where container_id is the identifier of container obtained from the previous command. Not everything needs to be restarted, so i am doing this manually.
What need to be restarted:

- kube-scheduler
- kube-controller-manager
- kube-flannel
- kube-proxy
- etcd
- all k8s_POD_* related to listed above